# In Middleman, how can I use the srcset attribute, and with relative file paths?

Tags: middleman

In Middleman, I can generate a relative image file path like so:

```
<%= tag :img, :src => "/images/down-caret-1x.png" %>
```

Which will output this:

```
<img src="/images/down-caret-1x.png">
```

I'd like to get an output that looks like this:

```
<img src="/images/down-caret-1x.png" srcset="/images/down-caret-2x.png 1000w">
```

Anyone know how to do that?

The [docs](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/file_size_optimization/) mention using this:

```
<img src="<%= image_path('100px.jpg') %>" srcset="<%= image_path('300px.jpg') %> 3x, <%= image_path('200px.jpg') %> 2x, <%= image_path('100px.jpg') %> 1x">
```

but I don't see anywhere to set the image_path variable or whatever that is.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set it in your `config.rb` like this:

```
set :images_dir, "path/to/images"
```

I found this blog quite useful for configuring middleman: https://richardkall.se/building-static-websites-with-middleman-part-two/

Comment: Thanks @troubalex- I appreciate the link and the answer. Cheers!